# Large current spike in turn on boost converter

Tags: inductor, boost

I have a circuit that boost voltage from 12V to 120V, the problem is the current in inductor is too big, around 5A, the circuit and the simulation in LTSpice is like this

[image]

the red line is the current, and the blue line is the voltage across zener diode, i just want to the big voltage without much current. how can i limit the current for around 1A? it is okey for the voltage to have a longer settling time

thank you

Comment: 1 way: reduce the duty cycle and only increase it slowly to reach the target output voltage. Another: Reduce C1.

Comment: You could use a lower duty cycle to start and then increase the duty cycle. Most (all?) real boost converters have an active control circuit instead of just a constant PWM signal.

Comment: A 1mH inductor seems a bit large, outside of duty cycle. Did you test with lower value inductors?

Comment: Why do you need Zener at the output since you will be using some sort of control loop? And your output capacitor is very large, for 120V, 300Ohm, 1% ripple it should be ~30uF. The inductor is quite large, but that's up to you to know whether you want CCm or DCM, current ripple, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is for higher current at startup is due to charging of output cap C1 which is usually called as inrush current. This inrush current will last longer till the output cap charges to input voltage level. Once output reaches input voltage level diode blocks it.

This type of problem will exist in "Hot plugging" system like battery.

Inrush can be approximately calculate by

Ipeak = Vin * sqrt(Cout/L)

approximate pulse time can be calculated by

Tpulse = Pi * sqrt(L * Cout)

There are two ways to solve this problem practically

1) Passive inrush current limiter

2) Active inrush current limiter

**Passive inrush current limiter**

This system includes Resistor (approx around 10 to 20 Ohm depends on practical application)

[image]

Resistor uses is of Thermistor (Resistance will drop due to rise of temperature which is due to current) type. This has its own disadvantage, resistor will get heat up lot since whole load current will pass through R1 & R2

**Active Current Limiter**

This includes Switch S1 in addition to R1&R2. S1 may be mechanical relay or any power electronics switch like Mosfet, SSR along with its control circuit.

[image]

This will serve the purpose but will include additional cost and complexity.

If there is any control over input voltage from previous stage can be solved. For simulation purpose try programmable input voltage source.

Answer (score 1):

Every time M1 closes, the inductor is placed across the incoming supply voltage. This causes current to linearly ramp up to some value. The value it ramps up to is time-dependant i.e. it depends on how long M1 is closed.

When M1 opens the energy stored in the inductor is transferred (via the diode) to the capacitor C1. If you keep turning M1 on and off at a fixed rate you transfer a fixed amount of energy per switching cycle and the voltage on the output keeps going up and up.

So, you have to control the duty cycle in order to regulate the output voltage. Plus, it is load dependant: with light loads (such as the 1 MΩ shown in your circuit) the duty cycle time has to be appropriate for that load else the voltage will be too high.

With heavier loads the duty cycle has to be bigger (more energy transfer per cycle) to regulate the output voltage.

So, with your load of 1 MΩ and a target voltage of 120 volts, the power needed is 14.4 mW. If you are switching at 10 kHz then the energy transfer per cycle needed to be 14.4 mW / 10,000 = 1.44 μJ.

If you have a duty cycle of 50%, M1 (at 10 kHz) will be "on" for 50 μs and this means that current ramps up to 60 mA. This is just a rearrangement of V = L.di/dt where V = 12 volts, L = 10 mH and dt is 50 μs.

That current of 60 mA in a 10 mH choke stores an energy of 36 μJ i.e. much much more than is needed to be released each cycle for a load of 1 MΩ.

These are my figures of course but you need to understand the workings of the math so you can appropriately correct the duty cycle of M1.

Please also note that the negative current you are seeing is only because the inductor in your circuit is positioned such a way as to give I(L1) a negative value.